# How do I change the windows 8.1 start screen to a custom background?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, start-screen

How to change custom background image in windows 8.1 start screen.
I was able to change default wallpapers in windows 8 but i can't changing in windows 8.1.

Comment: did you tryed right click on your selected image in folder and press ´Set as desktop background´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Start**, type *personalisation*, and click on **Change the background and colors on Start**:

[image]

There you can change the background pictures on the Start Screen. This should be no different to Windows 8.